# jQuery - function with a setInterval() being fired twice at once?

Tags: jquery, setinterval

I have a jQuery function that uses `setInterval()` to slowly type out a phrase--like with the phrase "string one", each character would be printed to the screen after a set number of milliseconds.

The problem is that in my code, I have two calls to the function one right after the other, and they're overlapping because it appears that `setInterval()` doesn't stop the normal flow of code. It's hard to explain, [here's my jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abluescarab/ymxu5/) that shows what happens.

Here's my function:

```
function type(text) {
    if(intv == null) {
        var textArray = text.split("");
        var length = textArray.length - 1;
        var i = 0;

        $("#div").append('<p class="text' + n + '"></p>' + "\n"); // creates a paragraph to print every character to (n is a global var)

        intv = setInterval(function() {
            if(i <= length) {
                var a = textArray[i];
                $('#div .text' + n).text($('#div .text' + n).text() + a); // appends the character to the paragraph created above
                i++;
            }
            else {
                alert("stopping interval..."); // just lets me know when the interval is stopping
                clearInterval(intv);
                intv = null;
                n++;
            }
        }, 60);
    }
    else {
        alert("the interval is not null"); // lets me know if the previous setInterval has stopped firing
    }
}
```

And here's how I'm calling it:

```
type("string one");
type("string two");
```

The problem is that both "string one" and "string two" end up firing at the same time, and either start infinitely looping or only the first one works.

I really don't know if there's a way to fix this, and my searches have yielded nothing. I don't know if this is a common problem or not. Is there a way that I can keep the second string from firing until the first one is done?

Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: What do you expect? They start at the same time, and both fire 60ms later, which then (obviously) also is at the same time.

Comment: @pimvdb Well, in my experience, if you call to a function twice in a row, the first one will finish before the second one starts.

Comment: @Abluescarab `setInterval` is asynchronous, so the first call will set an interval and the second one won't as one exists already.

Comment: You could add a callback like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ymxu5/3/

Comment: But I feel like you probably want the code to be simpler.

Comment: @Shmiddty I appreciate the code, but yes, if I do it this way, it will be very verbose. I'm planning on having this function called a lot. (On a semi-unrelated note, I see you changed the alerts, sorry about that, I just needed to make them obvious.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/ymxu5/12/

First, set up a function queue that will keep track of where we are:

```
function Queue(){
    this._fns = [];
    this._args = [];
    this._running = false;
    var that = this;

    this.add = function(fn){
        console.log(fn.name + " added");
        that._fns.push(fn);
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
        that._args.push(args);

        if (!that._running)
            that.next();

        return that;
    },
    this.next = function(){        
        if (that._fns.length == 0){
            that._running = false;
        }
        else{
            that._running = true;
            that._fns.shift().apply(that, that._args.shift());
        }
    }
};
```

You'll then need to adapt your methods to use `queue.next();`. I've set up the `Queue` object to call each function, changing the context of `this` to the `Queue` object, which is why `var queue = this;` is used.

```
function type(text){
    var queue = this;
    var $con = $("<p>").appendTo("#div");

    var typeText = function(con, txt, cursor){
        if (cursor < txt.length){
            con.text(con.text() + txt[cursor]);
            setTimeout(function(){
                typeText(con, txt, cursor + 1);
            }, 60);
        }
        else{
            setTimeout(function(){
                queue.next();
            }, 250);
        }
    };
    typeText($con, text.split(""), 0);
}

function flicker(sel){
    var queue = this;

    // note that this will cause issues if "sel" selects multiple things
    // because it will create multiple callbacks with jQuery, and `next` will
    // be called once for each item in "sel"
    $(sel).fadeOut("fast", function(){
        $(this).fadeIn("fast", function(){
            queue.next();
        });
    });
}
```

You'll want to have a `Queue` object accessible throughout your scope. I made it global here:

```
var q = new Queue();
var senNum = 0;

$(function(){    
    $("#button").click(function(){
        q.add(type, "Sentence " + (++senNum)).add(flicker, "p:nth-child("+senNum+")");
    });        
});
```

I also took the liberty of making the `add` method chainable, so you can use it like above.
​

here's an example of using a few methods to create a console-like interface:

http://jsfiddle.net/ymxu5/15/

Comment: There is an issue where if, after some time, you add another item to the queue, it won't work. So if you're not queueing up multiple items subsequently, you'll have to reset `n` and `queue`, or modify the code to know when something is working.

Comment: Will this keep running after that delay? It looks interesting.

Comment: Another comment! There's one problem: when I call something after the type function, it registers before the type function is finished. It's kind of similar to what was originally happening. So, for example, I use that setTimeout() function to type some text after a set period of time, but it starts firing at the beginning, like the type() function isn't being detected.

Comment: the type function is asynchronous. so if you call something directly after calling type, it will happen immediately unless you specify otherwise.

Comment: Crap, there we are with the asynchronicity again. Is there a way to make it synchronous? I appreciate the help so far, but I might just have to scrap the whole idea and take a different approach.

Comment: I think the best option would be to adapt some sort of timeout queue, not dissimilar to @primvdb's answer. Making the action synchronous won't allow you to have the "typing" animation that you want.

Comment: @Abluescarab look here: http://jsfiddle.net/ymxu5/9/ I couldn't make `type` completely ignorant of the queue, so you'll have to modify each function by calling `next()` when you've completed your action.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ymxu5/12/ Shows how you might apply other functionality to the queue.

Comment: @Schmiddty This works wonderfully! Thanks so much (and thanks for sticking around)!

Answer (score 3):

`setInterval` really only schedules an interval to be run every so many milliseconds. After that, everything still works, so you can use other modules on the page (it would be pretty useless if you wouldn't be able to).

If you do want to wait until interval #1 has completed, you can call a function that you pass. Something like:

```
function type(text, functionIfDone) {
// ...
            clearInterval(intv);
            functionIfDone();  // call the function now because the interval is over
```

Use it like:

```
type("string one", function() {
    type("string two");
});
```

---

If you would like not to use callbacks, then you could use some helper functions that take care of queueing: http://jsfiddle.net/pZtje/.

```
var currentInterval;
var intervals = [];

var startInterval = function(func, time) {
    intervals.push({
        func: func,
        time: time
    });
    checkQueue();
};

var checkQueue = function() {
    if(currentInterval == null) {
        var item = intervals.shift();
        if(item) {
            currentInterval = setInterval(item.func, item.time);
        }
    }
};

var stopInterval = function() {
    clearInterval(currentInterval);
    currentInterval = null;
    checkQueue();
};


// Usage:

var i = 0;
function foo() {
    console.log(i);
    i++;
    if(i === 3) {
        i = 0;
        stopInterval();
    }
}

startInterval(foo, 1000);
startInterval(foo, 1000);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Shmiddty recommended the same thing, is this the only way? Is there a way I can incorporate the callback without using an internal function? Like I said above, I'm planning on calling this function a lot, and if I have to do this, it will be a lot of code.

Comment: If worse comes to worse (which I suspect it might), I will definitely use this, though.

Comment: @Abluescarab: You can also use a little piece of helper code to avoid callbacks: http://jsfiddle.net/pZtje/.

Comment: Thanks! It's very verbose as well, but it's better than nothing and better than callbacks.

Comment: @Abluescarab: Yes, well, it depends on how you look at it. It's not baked into the language itself, so you *will* have to add some additional code. But if you include the little library above and act as if it *is* just available, then the actual usage code isn't too long. What I mean is, if `setInterval` wasn't available you'd also have to include some verbose library code to add it to the language.

Comment: I totally understand. I realize that "verbosity" is really the only way to go when a function isn't built-in. I appreciate the answer.